# ${relativeFileDirname} doesn't resolve in tasks.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Here's my `tasks.json` for reference:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "cppbuild",
      "label": "build active file with debug",
      "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
      "args": [
        "${file}",
        "-o",
        "${workspaceFolder}/out/${relativeFileDirname}.out",
        "-g"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
      "group": "build",
      "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/g++"
    },
  ]
}
```

Here's a video to demonstrate the output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHXvr.jpg

In the video I am compiling a file `12-how-to-debug-effectively/main.cpp`, and according to my `tasks.json`, the output file should be `out/12-how-to-debug-effectively.out`, but for some reason the variable substitution doesn't work and I instead get `out/.out`.

Any pointers where I might be going wrong?

Comment: what is the full command in the terminal that has `g++`

Comment: I don't know what you mean but `which g++` gives `/usr/bin/g++`

Comment: with just `/usr/bin/g++` you can't compile a program

Comment: Please tell me what I need to do then.

Comment: use a simple `echo` task and find out which variables do work when your editor is a cpp file https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_how-can-i-know-a-variables-actual-value

Comment: I tried the echo command out and it works as expected. I wonder why it isn't working in my build task then.

Comment: what if you replace the `${workspaceFolder}` with the actual value, so you have only 1 variable in the argument string

Comment: Doesn't work again. I wouldn't want to do that anyway since that'd make my task.json project specific.

Comment: it is just a test to see if the variable substitution can handle more than 1 variable in the string. Very strange that the echo version of `${relativeFileDirname}` gives you the correct result

Comment: Yes thats the weird thing. I think this is a bug?

Comment: Where have you find the example with `"type": "cppbuild"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cppbuild` is not a valid value for the `type` argument.

All the examples on the VSC doc site use `"type": "shell"`

When using `"type": "shell"` I can see the command to be executed and the variables are filled in correct. (I used a 1 word subdirectory `mysite`)

Using `"type": "cppbuild"` I can't see which command is executed.